# Function needed for HTML Registration

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to make a function so the html code will execute by calling the following function. What do i need to do to to translate it as a recognized function?

```
 function jquery_register(){

    }
```

here is the required HTML code

```
<div id="container">
        <form action="#" method="post">

            <!-- #first_step -->
            <div id="first_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>Reg Name</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="username" />
                    <label for="username">At least 4 characters. Uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers only.</label>

                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password" />
                    <label for="password">At least 4 characters. Use a mix of upper and lowercase for a strong password.</label>

                    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" value="password" />
                    <label for="cpassword">If your passwords aren’t equal, you won’t be able to continue with signup.</label>
                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="" />
            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #second_step -->
            <div id="second_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>Reg Name</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="first name" />
                    <label for="firstname">Your First Name. </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="last name" />
                    <label for="lastname">Your Last Name. </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="email address" />
                    <label for="email">Your email address. We send important administration notices to this address. </label>                    
                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #third_step -->
            <div id="third_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>Reg Name</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <select id="age" name="age">
                        <option> 0 - 17</option>
                        <option>18 - 25</option>
                        <option>26 - 40</option>
                        <option>40+</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="age">Your age range. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                    <select id="gender" name="gender">
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="gender">Your Gender. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                    <select id="country" name="country">
                        <option>United States</option>
                        <option>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option>Canada</option>
                        <option>Serbia</option>
                        <option>Italy</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="country">Your country. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_third" id="submit_third" value="" />

            </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->


            <!-- #fourth_step -->
            <div id="fourth_step">
                <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>Reg Name</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

                <div class="form">
                    <h2>Summary</h2>

                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Username</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Password</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Name</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Age</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Gender</td><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Country</td><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
                <input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />            
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="progress_bar">
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <div id="progress_text">0% Complete</div>
    </div>
```

After the function is called like i said it will execute on the page from this function and show the form.

I have the jquery functions which are already in place.

All i need to do is complete this bit of code.

Comment: I think you'll need a separate page to handle the form input which will get shoved into the url of the next page.  So I believe you can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ to pull the values out.

Answer (score 0):

you have several different ways to do this:

1- create a html file on the server side put your html on it, and use jQuery `load` function:

```
function jquery_register(){
    jQuery(document.body).load(html_file_url);
}
```

2- create the html file like the first solution, use jQuery ajax to load and inject it to your page:

```
function jquery_register(){
    jQuery.get(html_file_url).then(function(htmlstr, status){
        if(status == "success"){
            jQuery(document.body).html(htmlstr);
        }
    });
}
```

3- the other way here is define a variable in the client-side and do something like this:

```
function jquery_register(){
    var html_variable = '<div id="container">.....the rest';
    jQuery(document.body).html(html_variable);
}
```

4- or you can simply do:

```
document.body.innerHTML = html_variable;
```

or create a container in your page and:

```
document.getElementById("htmlcontainer").innerHTML = html_variable;
```